# Custom variable in block always giving last requested value in phtml file

Tags: blocks, custom-variable

I've injected custom variable named **slider_id** to my block like below,

```
    <reference name="content">
         <block type="sliderpro/sliderpro" name="defaultslider" as="defaultslider" before="-" template="sliderpro/defaultslider.phtml" >
               <action method="setData"><name>slider_id</name><value>1</value></action>
         </block>
         <block type="sliderpro/sliderpro" name="defaultslider" as="defaultslider" before="-" template="sliderpro/defaultslider.phtml" >
                <action method="setData"><name>slider_id</name><value>3</value></action>
          </block>
     </reference>
```

Under **defaultslider.phtml,**

```
echo $this->getSliderID(); // Outputs 3
```

I need to grab both the requested slider_id's  i,e 1 & 3.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<reference name="content">
     <block type="sliderpro/sliderpro" name="defaultslider" as="defaultslider" before="-" template="sliderpro/defaultslider.phtml" >
           <action method="setData"><name>slider_id</name><value>1,3</value></action>
     </block>
 </reference>
```

Then get the slider ids like this:

```
$sliderIds = explode(',', $this->getSliderId());
```

Then you will always have an array with ids even i you set the value to `1` or `1,3`.

**[EDIT]**
If you want 2 sliders on the page with 2 different ids, just give different names to the sliders in the xml.

```
<reference name="content">
     <block type="sliderpro/sliderpro" name="defaultslider" as="defaultslider" before="-" template="sliderpro/defaultslider.phtml" >
           <action method="setData"><name>slider_id</name><value>1</value></action>
     </block>
     <block type="sliderpro/sliderpro" name="defaultslider_1" as="defaultslider_1" before="-" template="sliderpro/defaultslider.phtml" >
            <action method="setData"><name>slider_id</name><value>3</value></action>
      </block>
 </reference>
```

Comment: Thats absolutely right, but i'm creating a slider module which gives unique block type on addition of every slider, user will grab and paste it on any page to display it. So i think this might confuse my client. Is there any other option ?

Comment: @Vinoth. See my update.

Comment: Yes It worked...